# enable guide access programmatically

Tags: ios

According to the description: "The request to lock this app into Single App mode will only succeed if the device is Supervised, and the app's bundle identifier has been whitelisted using Mobile Device Management."
To use guide access, we have to apply MDM, while: is there an way to test my code (for the guide access) before we apply MDM?

Comment: I don't think so. I've tried recently and I really had to deploy the app through MDM with an application bundle identifier provided in the whitelisted config by the MDM.

Comment: You can set single app/guided access mode without MDM but you cannot lock the device into that mode - A reboot will clear it - http://printhereapp.com/kiosk